# jar's so in aar can not be build to apk

Tags: android, jar, shared-libraries, aar

I have build a flutter module in to a aar,it's structure like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zEKW.png)

and then i use the aar in apk like this：
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiV5O.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVclX.png)
after bulid apk，jar's so cannot be package to the apk：
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9cyx.png)

this happen in android gradle plugin7.4.0

and i use the same way in one old project which android gradle plugin:'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3',then that's all the right way,the jar's so in aar can be package to apk :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1fn6.png)
what should i do,anyone else meet the problem

first build a aar which has some jar,and the jar has the so library,then the jar package into the aar's lib directory

Answer (score 0):

The content of your `.aar` file is not properly integrated into the final `.apk` file, because its structure violates the rules on how `.jar`, `.aar` and `.apk` files have to be stuctured. You might be interested in this [overview](https://timeout.userpage.fu-berlin.de/apk-building-on-mobile/en/index.php).

Your screenshot shows an `.aar` file which has a `libs` directory containing a `.jar` file which itself contains a `lib` directory with a ABI-specific directory with `.so` files. That's an invalid construct.

That `libs` directory contains `.jar` files, that's correct. But those `.jar` files -- in their role as Java class libraries -- have to contain `.class` files *only*, and no native libraries (`.so` files) at all. Native libraries have to be put into a directory named `lib` (not `jni` -- that name shall only used in projects, but not in `.aar` or `.apk` files), as you can see on that other [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9cyx.png) of yours.

So remember some points considering AARs:

**(1)** `libs` directory comprises `.jar` files, which *only* contain `.class` files (and some manifest stuff, but that's not important here).

**(2)** `lib` directory contains native shared libraries (`.so` files) in subdirectories named according each supported hardware platform type (ABI, so `armeabi-v7a`, `arm64-v8a`, `x86` and/or `x86-64`).